# Cleanup rabbitmq queue

Tags: juju, openstack, rabbitmq

how can I cleanup (delete messages) in a rabbitmq queue?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and rabbitmq-server 3.2.4-1

#### Example:

```
# rabbitmqctl list_queues -p openstack
Listing queues ...
...
notifications.info      372
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install amqp-tools
amqp-delete-queue -q name_from_queue
```

In this link you have more options:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313027/rabbitmq-how-do-i-delete-all-messages-from-a-single-queue

Comment: is there a way to cleanup the queue without deleting the queue?

Comment: It's also explained there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27950091

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to cleanup the queue without deleting the queue?

Yes; this is called *purging* the queue and there are plenty of ways to do it.

This is because in addition to being something that one can do with tools like `rabbitmqadmin` pointed at the broker it's an operation accessible directly from the protocol.  So people can write, and have written, tools that take queue names and enact the `queue.purge` method against them, in languages as varied as C++ and Python.

[The Ubuntu amqp-utils package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amqp-tools) is a little light on such tools, but one doesn't have to look far to find things like [Doug Barth's amqp-utils toolset](https://github.com/dougbarth/amqp-utils) written in Ruby and containing an `amqp-purge` utility.

The `rabbitmqadmin` syntax is:

```
rabbitmqadmin purge queue queue-name
```

### Further reading

- [`queue.purge`](http://rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#queue.purge). *AMQP 0-9-1 Quick Reference*. Pivotal Software. 2015.
- [`rabbitmqadmin`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html). Pivotal Software. 2015.
- Dick Brouwer (2012-08-23).  [*Purging an AMQP queue*](http://dickbrouwer.com/post/30066777016/purging-an-amqp-queue).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common operational action for Rabbit, then we should add an action to the juju charm so that it is easily invoked remotely without having to log on to the system. Juju would also take care to ensure that this was done at a time when nothing else was happening on the system (from an ops / deployment perspective obviously).